# Why does Watson Assistant service become Inactive?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

We have been using Lite plan of Watson Assistant services for over 2 years.
We have our bots running in production environment.
Yesterday, all of a sudden, our Watson Assistant services were turned inactive. The end users could not access the bots. I created a new service, and restored all of our bots, which took some effort.
Today morning, again, we see that our new WA service that created yesterday is turned 'Inactive'. I have restored the bots again by creating a new service again.
Does anyone know why this is happening? It is super annoying to see bots disappear from production. I don't see any notifications or logs.

Would be great if anyone could help. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that a support question? Moreover, IMHO the Lite plan is not intended for production environments. Maybe you reached some limits and it got inactive? Turn your question into a technical question by adding details or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Lite Plan is for PoC and Demo, not for production.
As far as I remember, if you exceed the API call limit, the instance is blocked until the end of the month, except if you upgrade to PLUS.
IBM doesn't provide specific SLAs. PLUS plans is the right one to use for production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Lite plan has a 10K messages limit per month.
See
https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/watson-assistant